# Rotated image not positioned like it should

Tags: ios, merge, uiimageview, rotation, draw

I have the following problem: I have two images - one background image and a logo image. I want to rotate the logo by 30 degrees, then merge it with the background image. The problem is that when I do that, the logo is not positioned where I want it to be. Here is my code:

```
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(673, 732);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [backgroundImg.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextRotateCTM(c, rotationSlider.value * M_PI / 180.0);
    [logoImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(logoImageView.frame.origin.x, logoImageView.frame.origin.y, logoImageView.bounds.size.width, logoImageView.bounds.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
    imageTwo = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Any ideas what is wrong with my code and how to improve it? The logo goes some pixels away every time. Here you can see what I am talking about:

Before merge:
[image]
After merge:
[image]

Any ideas?